# how to convert black icon to white using css for IE11

Tags: jquery, css

i used this css for converting icon from black to white. Please help me out

```
#sidebar ul li a img {
    filter: invert(100%);
    -webkit-filter: invert(1);
    -moz-filter: invert(100%);
   -o-filter: invert(100%);
   -ms-filter: invert(100%);
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Comment: What are you using: Icon or Image?

Comment: i am using black png icon

Comment: but that is also not working

Comment: It won't work in ie - I would either convert your png to an svg and then you can just change the fill colour with css; or use a font icon then you can just change the colour of the text

Comment: try with this:  `-webkit-filter: brightness(0) invert(1); filter: brightness(0) invert(1);`

Answer (score 0):

I used this with a gray icon and it works:

```css
filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
```